# Прочитать файлы лога, находящиеся в ежедневно создаваемых папках

Tags: linux, bash

Имеется следующая структура папок:

```
/home/tar/run/2023-06-02/9797/run.log
/home/tar/run/2023-06-02/9798/run.log
/home/tar/run/2023-06-02/9799/run.log
```

Соответственно, ежедневно создаётся новая пачка с другими именами. Задача: извлечь содержимое логов за последнюю дату в один файл. Затык в том, что не могу понять правильно загнать это в переменную.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795678/append-date-to-filename-in-linux

Comment: Что нибудь такое попробовать `cat /home/tar/run/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d)/*/run.log > ./$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')_full.log`

Comment: Спасибо за идею.

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось довольно просто:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
findlog=$(find /home/tar/run/"$date"/* -type f -name "log")
cat $findlog > /var/log/run.log
```